# Enable caching for url query parameters in aws api gateway with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "MyDemoMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.proxy" = true
    "method.request.querystring.tableid" = true
  }
}
```

With this script, I am trying to add a URL query parameter named *tableid* with caching enabled. But I can see no documentation referring to enabling the caching.

[image: Resulting configuration of this code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, this can be done using `cache_key_parameters` and `cache_namespace` below the **`aws_api_gateway_integration`** as follows:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "MyDemoMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"

  request_parameters = {
    "method.request.path.proxy" = true
    "method.request.querystring.tableid" = true
  }
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "MyDemoIntegration" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id          = aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id
  http_method          = aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method
  type                 = "MOCK"
  cache_key_parameters = ["method.request.querystring.tableid"]
  cache_namespace      = "mycache" 
}
```

This was introduced in this Pull Request https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/893.

Comment: Thanks !!. _cache_key_parameters_ and _cache_namespace_ are not allowed in **aws_api_gateway_method**. I added it in **aws_api_gateway_integration** for the same method without changing anything on **aws_api_gateway_method** and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for testing it. I've just fixed the answer!